# Use selected value in postgis function

Tags: postgis, sql, java, nearest-neighbor

How can I use the selected value from a `SELECT` statement in a PostGIS function.

e.g.
using the `geom_way` from

`SELECT geom_way FROM osm_2po_4pgr ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(21.323329 39.948928)', 4326), geom_way) ASC LIMIT 1;`

in

`SELECT  ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(geom_way, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(21.323329 39.948928)'));`

EDIT: I know this has errors, but what I really want to know is how I could refactor a super long statement like this:

`SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Line_Interpolate_Point((SELECT geom_way FROM osm_2po_4pgr ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(39.948928 21.323329)', 4326), geom_way) ASC LIMIT 1), ST_Line_Locate_Point((SELECT geom_way FROM osm_2po_4pgr ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(39.948928 21.323329)', 4326), geom_way) ASC LIMIT 1), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(21.323329 39.948928)',4326))));`

To be manageable enough to fit into a `Java` `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple subquery:

```
SELECT ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(q.geom_way, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(21.323329 39.948928)'))
FROM
  (SELECT geom_way 
  FROM osm_2po_4pgr 
  ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(21.323329 39.948928)', 4326), geom_way) ASC 
  LIMIT 1) 
 AS q
```